# Laravel MorphToMany Doesn't Work for multi columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-relations

Laravel version: 7.0 Here is my table.

```
Schema::create('model_email_form', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('model_type');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('email_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('form_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Here is my `Service` model.

```
public function forms()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(
        Form::class,
        'model',
        'model_email_form',
        'model_id',
        'form_id'
    );
}

public function emails()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(
        Email::class,
        'model',
        'model_email_form',
        'model_id',
        'email_id'
    );
}
```

I inserted data in `model_email_form` table but when I get `service model` object, `emails` and `forms` have null object.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: MorphToMany is for polymorphic many-to-many. The model_email_form table you have provided is not correct for this. Also, please describe in more detail the raltionships between Form, Email and Service. Are there many Forms that relate to more models than Service? Likewise, are there many Emails that relate to more models than Service? Is there a reason you want both polymorphic relations to be stored on the same table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The relationships between Form, Email and Service are all many-to-many, and the reason why I put form_id and email_id together there is that service requires the both.

Comment: It can require both, and not have them in the same table. I will make an answer on my interpretation of what is suitable and if it is not suitable, I will delete it

Comment: I just separated them into two tables. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, I just found the issue. My fault. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved your issue, my solution below is how I would implement these relationships.

Comment: if my answer is in line with the solution please give it an upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comments:

There are Form, Email and Service. Forms can be associated with any number of different types of models. Emails can be associated with any number of different types of models. A Service can have many Forms and a Service can have many Emails.

Using that as the basis, this would be our schema:

```
Schema::create('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name'); // as an example
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('formables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('form_id'); // the id of the form
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('formable_id'); // the associated model's id
    $table->string('formable_type'); // The associated model's class name
});

Schema::create('emails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('subject'); // as an example
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('emailables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('email_id'); // the id of the email
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('emailable_id'); // the associated model's id
    $table->string('emailable_type'); // The associated model's class name
});

Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name'); // as an example
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

With that schema, we can create the following models with the following relationships:

```
class Form extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Service::class, 'formable');
    }
   
    // Add the other morphedByMany relationships of forms
}

class Email extends Model
{
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Service::class, 'emailable');
    }
   
    // Add the other morphedByMany relationships of emails
}

class Service extends Model
{
    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->morphedToMany(Form::class, 'formable');
    }
   
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->morphedToMany(Email::class, 'emailable');
    }
}
```